# installing yum from scratch on centos after mistakenly erarsing the python on a whole from centos 6.7

Tags: centos, yum

Mistakenly I deleted the python, which in result also corrupted the yum, now i cant install yum as it has many dependencies. Can anyone of you help me in getting the yum fiasco fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install all dependencies packages one bye one on your server through RPM. There is no other way to get this fix.

Comment: Hi, can you list down all the dependencies which i need to install and rpm path for the same, as i have read many articles and they differ in their dependency list.